# Generate IAM policy based on CloudFormation template?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

To easier follow the principal of least privilege, is there a way to generate the necessary IAM policy based on a CloudFormation template?

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed use cloudformation to create policies via `AWS::IAM::Policy` resource.
Here is the documentation  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-policy.html

Comment: I'm actually looking for a service that analyses a complete template and generates a policy document with only the necessary permissions to create (and update, rollback, delete) the resources in the template.

Comment: That is not your question. This is the problem with such short questions, with not much to go by to answer. Considering you are the one looking for answers, you should provide as much information as possible in your question so answers can help you.
The tool you are looking for is AWS IAM Access Analyzer: "https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/what-is-access-analyzer.html"
You can use that retroactively by looking at CloudTrail, for example, and see which api calls are being made to determine what is not needed.

Comment: I'm afraid there is not much more information I could add to the question. The tool you linked could be useful but it seems it demands a system already up and running. I'm looking for a tool that could generate the necessary policy based only on the template.